# Reset password functionality

Tags: passwords

If the password reset form can be accessed only by logged in user, what are the mandatory and good to have fields the form should contain?

Comment: If it can only be accessed by a logged in user, why is it a password reset form and not a change password form?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_weak_password_change_or_reset_functionalities_(OTG-AUTHN-009)

Answer (score 1):

As @AndrolGenhald points out, the words "Reset password functionality" usually means the "I forgot my password" workflow. The idea of having "Reset password functionality" that can only be accessed by a logged in user does not make sense.

I will assume you mean "Change password functionality", like when you press ctrl+alt+del in Windows.

---

I think the only field that is mandatory is a "Confirm your password" or equivalent. If your app supports multi-factor authentication (aka MFA / 2FA) then you should force the user to go through the full login workflow again before presenting them the "change password" form. The idea is that finding someone else's laptop unlocked should not be enough to change their password.